# lazy="extra" fetch in hibernate java don't work

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem with `lazy="extra"` fetch in hibernate in java.

I created two classes, parent and child. In the parent class, I defined the following fields :

```
public class Parent{ 

...

@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent")

@IndexColumn(name="index", base=1)

**@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)**

   private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();

   public List<Child> getChildren() {
    return children;
   }

   public void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
    this.children = children;
   } 

...

}
```

respectively, in the Child class  i have this parent field definition

```
public class Child{
...

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  optional = true)

 @JoinColumn(name = "parent_ID", nullable = true)

private Parent parent;

 public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
   }

public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
   }

...

}
```

But when I call in my utility class to get   parent.getChildren().size()  i have  an error

*failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.realcommerce.formsGenerator.entity.Parent.children, no session or session was closed*

can  somebody help me to understand what I did wrong, and why my code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error normally happens if you do the following:

1. open session
2. select parent data
3. close session
4. access data with lazy loading (p. ex. parent.getChildren())

In step 4. you get this error, because Hibernate tries to load the data with lazy loading, which is not possible because you've already closed the session.

Check your code: When do you close the session.

The solution for solving this problem is either not to close the session or to access the lazy data before closing the session, even if not needed in that moment.